# find query with a condition to a sub property desn't find the model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to make a simple `findOne` request, i have an isue trying to set a condition on a "sub property".

the model i am trying to find does exist on my bdd, but i go everytime on the `else` case:

```
Model.findOne({ email : { value: 'toto@gmail.com' } }, 'username email', function(error, User){
    if (error){
        console.log('Error query.');
    }else if (User){
        console.log('User found from email.'); //Expected to go here
    }else{
        console.log('Any user found.'); //Goes here everytime
    }
});
```

I guess it's normal since my other queries which are not on "sub properties" work well, so what is the way to do it (find a model from a "sub property") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to query on a field of a subdocument:

```
Model.findOne({ 'email.value': 'toto@gmail.com' }, ...
```